# Android How many items can a list fit while scrolling with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a simple recyclerView. When scrolling, items are getting fetched from a Room Database and being added to the recycler's list.

I wondering how many items can be added before throws OOM?

Is there any way to control this?
Example: In instagram's search section you cant scroll down forever right?

Comment: It would add rows forever until you reach the limit of ArrayList :)  Please read concept of recycler view.

Comment: @PankajKumar And when i will reach ArrayList's limit? After scrolling for a while, OOM is inevitable?

Comment: No. In that case also you will not have OOM issue as RecyclerView reuses cells you will never have this issue. BUT your other logic may cause OOM which I think you know such things.

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView` creates limited number of views, then populate them by your data. So, there is no limits to show the items until some problems happened like reaching the `Integer` MAX_VALUE (because of containing list position), etc...

Comment: Irrelevant answer. Iam asking about the ArrayList inside RecyclerView.

Comment: Since there is an array in ArrayList data structure and the positioning of array is done by integer values (at most about 2 billions), there is a limit on ArrayList size and subsequently RecyclerView which is uses ArrayList. However, no mobile device exists with memory that supports about 2 billions data objects to show in RecyclerView.

Comment: So if i scroll for a very long time, app will throw OOM? or can i handle this somehow?

Comment: By pagination you can handle large list loading. So there limited number of items exist in memory at the same time. Look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging. I think it's helpful.

Comment: Yeah i know but if i keep scrolling even with pagination, i will in some point get close to Array's limit.

Comment: If you would be able to scroll items with speed of 100 items per second, this work takes about 248 days. So, you can't reach this limitation dude :)